3D background using helix.toolkit
I want to make 3D background in WPF using helix.toolkit. For example, I want to make skybox, but I don't how to do that. please help me.
I tried to make new texture using 6 images(x,y,z) as three.js but not working.
There are six images for cube box background, And I made that using three.js in WPF but not working in helix.toolkit. Please help me if anyone knows.

Do you have any WPF code to show? Also a picture of what you want would be good.

I don't have any idea about this. I don't know what I have to do.

If you want others to help you, you need to share (ideally code or screen shots) what you have done. It's not possible to help you with the information provided so far.

<helix:PanoramaCube3D Source="Resources"/> I used this code for 3D background, but the main problem is when i use that there's 3D background but when I add new element from point data, it is placed with background, so not working.
